# Why i calculate this limit like this?

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate $ \lim_{x \to ∞} f(x) = ($$\frac{x^2-2x+7}{x^2+3x+1})^\frac{1}{\sin(1/x)}$

The solution involves using $ \lim_{t \to 0} (1+t)^\frac{1}{t}=e $

But can i say that if $ \lim_{x \to ∞}  ($$\frac{x^2-2x+7}{x^2+3x+1})$ = 1

and  $ \lim_{x \to ∞}\frac{1}{\sin(1/x)} = 1 $

then $ \lim_{x \to ∞} f(x) = ($$\frac{x^2-2x+7}{x^2+3x+1})^\frac{1}{\sin(1/x)} = 1$?

I guess it's wrong but I don't really know why

Comment: How does $\lim_{x \to ∞}\frac{1}{sin(1/x)} = 1$?

Comment: $\sin(0)=0$.  Perhaps you confused this with $\cos(0)=1$

Comment: I did confuse. But if it was cos(1/x) then my solution is still wrong?

Comment: One of my professors used to claim *"we are always closer to zero than to infinity"*. So, start with $x=\frac 1t$, think about logarithms ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the limit exists, let

$\displaystyle L:= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{x^2-2x+7}{x^2+3x+1}\right)^\frac{1}{\sin(1/x)}$

Then we have:
$$\log L=\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sin(1/x)} \log \left(\frac{x^2-2x+7}{x^2+3x+1}\right)$$
Since

$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \sim  \frac{1}{x} \quad \text{as}\quad x\to+\infty\\
\log \left(\frac{x^2-2x+7}{x^2+3x+1}\right)=\log \left(1+\frac{-5x+6}{x^2+3x+1}\right)\sim \frac{-5x+6}{x^2+3x+1}
$$
It follows that:
$$\frac{1}{\sin(1/x)} \log \left(\frac{x^2-2x+7}{x^2+3x+1}\right)\sim \frac{6x-5x^2}{x^2+3x+1} \to -5 \quad \text{as}\quad x\to+\infty$$
Finally $$\boxed{L=\text{e}^{-5}}$$